# Adding Commas to Delineate a File using Python

Tags: python

I have many .txt files full of data that need to be read into python and then converted to one excel document. I have the code working to read the data, remove first 5 lines and last two lines and then also export all txt files into an excel file but the problem I'm running into now is that the TXT file has inconsistent use of white space so a simple white space delimiter is not working as it should.

Here is an example of the txt file.

```
2020MAY16 215015  2.0 1004.4  30.0  2.0 2.0 2.0  NO LIMIT  OFF  OFF  OFF  OFF -25.84 -32.50  CRVBND   N/A   -0.0   28.52   78.54  FCST    GOES16 33.4
```

*This is all on one line in the text file

Id like to be able to take this and make it look like this,

```
2020MAY16, 215015,  2.0, 1004.4,  30.0,  2.0, 2.0, 2.0,  NO LIMIT,  OFF,  OFF,  OFF,  OFF, -25.84, -32.50,  CRVBND,   N/A,   -0.0,   28.52,   78.54,  FCST,    GOES16, 33.4,
```

I have added the portion of code below that grabs the file from the URL address the user enters, iterates through the amount of storms to change the URL text. This also removes the top 5 lines and bottom 2. So if anyone has any suggestion on adding commas in that would be great to allow for an easy conversion to CSV file later.

```
for i in range(1,10,1):
    url = mod_string+str(i)+"L-list.txt"
    storm_abrev = url[54:57:1]     #Grabs the designator from the URL to allow for simplistic naming of files
    File_Name = (storm_abrev)+".txt"  #Names the file
    print(url)                      #Prints URL to allow user to confirm URLS are correct
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,File_Name)  #Sends a request to the URL from above, grabs the file, and then saves it as the designator.txt
    file = open(File_Name,"r")
    Counter = 0

    Content = file.read()
    CoList = Content.split("\n")

    for j in CoList:
        if j:
            Counter += 1

    print("This is the number of lines in the file")
    print(Counter)
    Final_Count = (Counter-2)
    print(Final_Count)

    with open(File_Name,'r') as f:
        new_lines = []
        for idx, line in enumerate(f):
            if idx in [x for x in range(5,Final_Count)]:
                new_lines.append(line)

    with open(File_Name,"w") as f:
        for line in new_lines:
            f.write(line)
```

Comment: `line = line.replace(" ", ", ")`

Comment: The issue is you are using a single space as a delimiter, but you also have a single space in some strings such as NO LIMIT.

Comment: The problem with your text file is your delimiter (single space) also occurs in fields which creates an ambiguity.  That's the reason files that use a single space as a delimiter place text fields in quotes to avoid this ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Fixed the issue caught by @DarryIG.

1. Create a list of phrases that need to remain intact. Let's call it `phrase_list`.
2. Identify a character or string that will never be used in the input file. For example, here I am assuming that an underscore will never be found in the input file and assign it to the variable `forbidden_str`. We could also use something like `%$#%$#^%&%_@^` - chances of something like that occurring is very rare.
3. Replace multiple spaces with single spaces. Then replace spaces in phrases to `_` (forbidden_str). Then replace all spaces with commas. Finally, replace `_`s back to spaces.

You could also simplify the reading lines part of your code using `readlines()`.

```
...
phrase_list = ['NO LIMIT']
forbidden_str = "_"

with open(File_Name,'r') as f:
    new_lines = f.readlines()
    new_lines = new_lines[5:Final_Count]
    

with open(File_Name,"w") as f:
    for line in new_lines:
        for phrase in phrase_list:
            if phrase in line:
                line = line.replace(phrase, phrase.replace(" ", forbidden_str))
        line = line.replace(" ", " ") # replaces multiple spaces with single spaces
        line = line.replace(" ", ",")
        line = line.replace(forbidden_str, " ")
        f.write(line)
```

Output:

```
2020MAY16,215015,2.0,1004.4,30.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,NO LIMIT,OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF,-25.84,-32.50,CRVBND,N/A,-0.0,28.52,78.54,FCST,GOES16,33.4,
```

Also, a quick suggestion. It's a good practice to name variables in lower case. For example, `final_count` instead of `Final_Count`. Upper cases are usually used for classes, instances, etc. It just helps in readability and debugging.

Comment: Issue with this approach is strings like `NO LIMIT` will have a comma inserted.

Comment: @DarrylG, good catch! May have to pre-define a list of such word combinations and use Regex.

Comment: @DarrylG, just fixed the issue with words like 'NO LIMIT'.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, I will look into Regex and pre-defining a list of words that cause issues... and yes, I will be going back through the code to lower case all the variable names. That's just me being new to coding!

Comment: @ZacharyTuggle, I edited my code and fixed that issue without Regex. Pls have a look. If Regex is better, pls share as I am not an expert on Regex.

Comment: @KrishnakanthAllika We are very close, i added the segment of code you suggested and this was the out put. problem now is a different amount of spaces between data. 2020MAY16,215015,,2.0,1004.4,,30.0,,2.0,2.0,2.0,,NO LIMIT,,OFF,,OFF,,OFF,,OFF,-25.84,-32.50,,CRVBND,,,N/A,,,-0.0,,,28.52,,,78.54,,FCST,,,,GOES16,33.4,

Comment: To clarify, goal is to have every data point separated by a single comma, no space. So it reads 2020MAY16,215015,2.0,1004.4,30.0, .... and so on.

Comment: Adding this `line = line.replace("  ", " ")`  before replacing with commas will fix that problem. This will replace all multiple spaces with single spaces and then single spaces to commas. Check my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, you have a list of lines where you want to replace a space with a comma followed by a space. In python you can do this very simple like this:

```py
lines = [x.replace(" ", ", ") for x in lines]
```

Comment: Issue with this is strings like `NO LIMIT` will have a comma inserted.

Comment: then just do an if statement for those known specific cases?

Comment: @JakobGuldbergAaes -- considering this could be an arbitrary size file with unknown strings (apriori).  How would you use if statements to distinguish strings with spaces vs. separate fields in such a file (i.e. could be thousands of such strings)?

Comment: Is there a finite number of string that you would like to exclude from being seperated or is that also unknown? If it is the latter, then there is not much you can do as you do not know where to seperate the lines.

Comment: You could for example make a dictionary of all fields with comma's like `fields = {"NO, LIMIT": "NO LIMIT"}` and use `for key, val in fields.items():    lines =  [x.replace(key, val) for x in lines]`